# JSF/Richfaces Re-render not calling validation

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a JSF/Richfaces page with a form containing number of components.
Some of these components are mandatory, so the **required** attribute is set to true.

I have a commandButton (C1), which calls a server operation. Based on the result of the server operation a field of type h:selectOneMenu (F1)is populated. This field is mandatory and its value is either manually selected by the user or populated via the server operation.

The problem appears when the form is submitted without a value in field F1. Naturally the validation fails and the error message “value is required” (or whatever the value of requiredMessage attribute is) is displayed. If the user then executes the server operation the F1 field is populated with the returned value and it is reRendered.  It seems, however, that the validation is not being performed on the client side and the field is still displayed as   in error. Even if the user manually selects a value after that the field is still displayed as invalid.
I’ve been searching on the internet, but couldn’t find a similar case.

Here are some excerpts from my page:

```
<a:region>
    <s:decorate id="alField" template="#{template}">
    <ui:define name="label">Al</ui:define>
        <h:inputTextarea id="al" maxlength="75"   valueChangeListener="#{aEntHome.clearFields}" 
            requiredMessage="Required" required="true"  value="#{aEntHome.instance.al}" >
            <f:validator validatorId="stringNotEmtyTrimmedValidator" />
            <a:support event="onblur" reRender="F1Field"  bypassUpdates="true" />                   
        </h:inputTextarea>

    <a:commandButton value="Search" image="img.GIF" id="searchImg" 
        action="#{lSearch.search}" reRender="F1Field,alField">
    </a:commandButton>
</s:decorate>
</a:region>

<s:decorate id="F1Field" template="#{template}">
  <ui:define name="label">F1</ui:define>
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{aEntHome.instance.f1}"    required="true"  >
    <s:selectItems value="#{listH.f1List}" var="_c" label="#{_c.f1Code}(#{_c.f1Name})"  />  
    <s:convertEntity />             
  </h:selectOneMenu>    
</s:decorate>
```

And this is the template used for displaying the fields:

```
<ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib">

    <div class="prop">

    <s:label styleClass="longName #{invalid?'errors':''}">
        <ui:insert name="label"/>
        <s:span styleClass="required" rendered="#{required}">*</s:span>
    </s:label>


    <span class="value #{invalid?'errors':''}">
        <s:validateAll>
            <ui:insert/>
        </s:validateAll>
    </span>

    <span class="error">
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/error.gif" rendered="#{invalid}" styleClass="errors"/>
        <s:message styleClass="errors"/>
    </span>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Could someone suggest what might be going wrong with this code?

Just to clarify - I am using Richfaces 3.3.1

I would really appreciate any clues as to what is causing this.

Comment: Where do the messages appear? If it's outside the rerender then they are going to stay there.

Comment: The messages appear next to the field. Here's the template that is used:   
    <div class="prop">

        <s:label styleClass="longName #{invalid?'errors':''}">
            <ui:insert name="label"/>
            <s:span styleClass="required" rendered="#{required}">*</s:span>
        </s:label>
<span class="value #{invalid?'errors':''}">
            <s:validateAll>
                <ui:insert/>
            </s:validateAll>
        </span>
        <span class="error">
            <h:graphicImage value="/img/error.gif" rendered="#{invalid}" styleClass="errors"/>

Comment: <s:message styleClass="errors"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</ui:composition>

I apologise for the formating, but there seems to be a limit on a comment.

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question. My question is is the <s:message> getting rerendered or not?

Comment: The funny thing is that the text in <s:message> is not displayed, but the appearance of the field stays the same (in red, in my case)

Comment: For those interested in the solution - it can be found here https://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/jsf-and-myfaces-howtos/backend/clear-input-components.html